# Gitblit push rejected reason not shown in intelij-idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitblit

If I add a hook that rejects a push, on Eclipse or other git client, the reject message is shown.
However if I am using intelij-idea, the reject reason is not shown.

Can this be configured to also show in JIdea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to open the [**version control tool**](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/version-control-tool-window.html)

**The tool window consists of several tabs:**

#### *Console tab*:

This tab shows the results of executing VCS-related commands.

#### *Update Info tab*:

This tab becomes available when local information is synchronized with the server.